# get directories size by recursion worked fine with one path and not with other path

Tags: powershell

This powershell snippet should display size and name of the files in directory on shared drive,

working fine with one path raising error with other path

copied two logs which raise error(log2) and other worked fine(log1)

for long path issue i tried like `$joined_path2=Join-Path -LiteralPath '\\?\UNC\' -ChildPath $joined_path`

```
$check_dir_path=\\XXXXXX.yy.NN.com\qeshare\Environments #(not working)
#check_dir_path=\\XXXXXX.yy.NN.com\qeshare\Environments\Private\ccccc #(working fine with this path)

$folders_in_dir=Get-ChildItem $check_dir_path -directory | Foreach-Object {$_.Name} 
foreach($folder in $folders_in_dir){
$joined_path=Join-Path -Path $check_dir_path -ChildPath $folder
#$joined_path2=Join-Path -Path '\\?\UNC\' -ChildPath $joined_path(tried not working)
#write-host $joined_path2
$files_sub = Get-ChildItem -Path  $joined_path -Recurse
if($files_sub.count -gt 0){
$size_dir = ($files_sub | Measure-Object -Sum Length).Sum
Write-Host "$size_dir_padded $folder `r`n"

}
```

LOG1 (no issue):

```
size(bytes)          file name

738621 PICK_PATH 

2296972 TaskRand-Emailbuild 

43961103 Task9-changetoTM1 

11846548 Task10-linuxlogin
```

LOG2 (issue):

```
size(bytes)          file name
62945815 BASS2 Rebase 

24696625 JAZN-April04
```

Error messages:

```
Get-ChildItem : The given path's format is not supported.
At C:\BBBB_task\file_size_check.ps1:28 char:
+ $files_sub = Get-ChildItem -Path  $joined_path -Recurse
+              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ChildItem], NotSupportedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.NotSupportedException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
 
: ReadError: (\\slcnas463.us....rea\ADS30207754:String) [Get-ChildItem], PathTooLongException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
 
Get-ChildItem : The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.
At C:\gopala_task\file_size_check.ps1:28 char:14
+ $files_sub = Get-ChildItem -Path  $joined_path -Recurse
+              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo
```

Comment: Please format your question properly

Comment: **[1]** Surround the check_dir_path with quotes as in `$check_dir_path = '\\XXXXXX.yy.NN.com\qeshare\Environments'` so the dots won't be an issue **[2]** Check the result of `Join-Path -Path '\\?\UNC\' -ChildPath $joined_path` because you need to strip the double backslashes of the path first. Now you'll get `\\?\UNC\\XXXXXX.yy.NN.com\qeshare\Environments\Private\ccccc` where it should be `\\?\UNC\XXXXXX.yy.NN.com\qeshare\Environments\Private\ccccc`